# android native app testing-appium with saucelabs

Tags: appium, saucelabs

I have created script using selenium (JAVA) for testing Android native app with appium.

issue:- I am unable to run my script on saucelab emulator.

Steps:-
1. I created free account in saucelabs and uploaded my .apk file in temporary storage of saucelabs using command:-
curl –u rajeevkumar:d5fd1f02-1b3e-457c-bb82-fc47b7dfc01d –X POST –H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/storage/rajeevkumar/xyz.apk?overwrite=true --data-binary @xyz.apk

2. .apk file uploaded successfully on saucelabs.
3. I copy paste the Desired capabilities from saucelab to my code (on which emulator i want to run).
4. When i run my code then app gets successfully installed on saucelabs emulator (i can check in saucelab dashboard page with unnamed job) but it throws exception while finding elements.
5. Do i need to add more stuff from saucelabs to my script? for running my app on saucelabs.

Comment: Do post the code and Error logs

Comment: @Madhan:-pls download the logs from  https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/29d19535c145f2345afe6c0e0c520f4220160713064124/7cd1ef

Comment: pls help!!. i am still confused:(